# What auth do I need to use for a web application that will only run from a php page and display on a large display?

Tags: google-maps-engine

Using: PHP HTML JS AJAX

I am developing a maps engine piece for a client with a freight scheduling service. The goal is to have one map that displays on a single LARGE display in their office and on each user's work station. It will be completely controlled in the background of the site. The map will have markers for eachof their drivers which will be clickable to display info about the driver's status.

Since there will be no other access, do I need to use anything like OAuth or will a simple api key do.

Thanks for help you can provide.

Ed

Answer (score 0):

If the information is not sensitive, you can just use an API key. If it is, then I suggest putting it in a password protected directory.

See [Using Basic Authentication (htaccess) to restrict access to a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404470/using-basic-authentication-htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-a-specific-url) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a layer or map publicly in Maps Engine, which would allow anyone to view the map, but would mean you don't need to set up any authentication (though depending on how you access the data, you may need an API key).

If your data is not public, you *will* need to use some form of OAuth. If your "large screen" is non-interactive (i.e. you can't have someone log in and click things) then you can only use the [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/serviceaccount) flow, as all of the other OAuth flows require a human.

It's not clear how you are going to display the data, so I can't give you any more specific advice. There are a number of ways to display data that's hosted in Maps Engine (e.g. [MapsEngineLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers), the [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) or access directly to [the API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. The "large display" is not to be interactive and it will change as driver locations, etc change by a method call in the drivers maintenance page. The users will allowed as a group to view and click on the driver markers as needed - I think...   This is my first crack at a Googl API so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Good luck! If you keep the data fresh in Maps Engine, then something like MapsEngineLayer should do the trick.

Comment: Mark,thanks again. I am already working on the layer for the map. I figure it is the simplest way to go.